# AWS Greengrass subprocess commands not working

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi

I am running greengrass on my Raspberry Pi 3 device, I ran into issues where Raspberry Pi doesnt resolve DNS properly with some routers and to do a workaround I run the following python script:

```
import urllib2
import subprocess
import platform
import time

def internet_on():
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output("ping -{} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system().lower()=="windows" else 'c', "a2jcwnhq2encoj.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"), shell=True)

    except Exception, e:
        print "internet is off"
        return False
    print "internet is on"
    return True

def fire_dns_corrector():
    if platform.system().lower() != "windows":
        print "running resolver"
        bash_command = "bash /home/pi/nameresolution.sh"
        print bash_command
        subprocess.Popen(bash_command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print "cannot resolve internet while running windows"
```

The above code works fine when I run the python as-is from a command line, however crashes the greengrass core when run through it via a Lambda function.

I get the following error in crash.log (all of it in one go):

```
/bin/sh: 1: ping: not found
/bin/sh: 1: ping: not found
/bin/sh: 1: ping: not found
/bin/sh: 1: ping: not found
```

The script calling the module I provided above goes something like:

```
def check_internet():
    if net_check.internet_on() is False:
        net_check.fire_dns_corrector()

check_internet()
```

Comment: have you tried other command than `ping`? have you tried using absolute path instead of relying on PATH environment?

Comment: I tried other commands, didnt work. I didn't try the absolute path.. where is ping located exactly?

Comment: Maybe, you should create a resource in your Greengrass group.